# General form of rational function which restricts to bijection on unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rational function which is bijective on unit disk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125105/rational-function-which-is-bijective-on-unit-disk)

I am trying to find the general form of rational function which restricts to a bijection on the unit disk.

Thanks

Comment: This question looks similar to [Rational function which is bijective on unit disk](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125105/rational-function-which-is-bijective-on-unit-disk).